# HTML radio button always submits last option to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

No matter what option is chosen, this code will always submit the second option to PHP.

Here is my form:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modalContent">
        <div class="modalHeader">
        <p>Add an income / expense</p>
        <span class="closeBtn" onclick="closeit()">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <form class="insertData" action="insert.php" method="post" id="form">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" required>
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <select name="category" required>
            <option value="food">Food</option>
            <option value="bills">Bills</option>
            <option value="rent">Rent</option>
            </select>
            <label for="amount">Amount</label>
            <div class="radios">
            <input type="radio" name="ie" value="income"><p>Income</p>
            <input type="radio" name="ie" value="expense"><p>Expense</p>
            </div>
            <input type="number" name="amount" required>
            <label for="description">Description (optional)</label>
            <textarea type="text" name="description"></textarea>
            <input id="start" type="text" name="start" value="" required style="display:none;">
            <input id="end" type="text" name="end" value="" required style="display:none;">
            <input class='submitBtn' type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the PHP (just echoing for debugging purposes right now):

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['ie']);
}
```

The data is going in via AJAX here (using FullCalendar)

```
select: function (start, end) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('start').value = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,
                    "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                document.getElementById('end').value = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end,
                    "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                $('form.insertData').on('submit', function () {
                    var that = $(this),
                        url = that.attr('action'),
                        type = that.attr('method'),
                        data = {};

                    that.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
                        var that = $(this),
                            name = that.attr('name'),
                            value = that.val();

                        data[name] = value;
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: type,
                        data: data,
                        success: function (response) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            location.reload();
                            document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style
                                .display = 'none';
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            },
```

No matter what option is chosen it will always submit 'expense'.
If I swap them around on the form then it will always submit 'income', so it seems to be always the last option is being submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because you loop all element has name attribute, and get the value. Including radio button. If you want to get selected radio button you must add if, for check if radio button has checked.
You can use code below, this code simpleer then you must check radio button:

```
$('form.insertData').on('submit', function () {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: $('form.insertData').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            location.reload();
            document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style
                .display = 'none';
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```